# How to unit test string extension method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a bit of code as follows which I would like to unit test which is an extension method on the string class:

```
public static string Replace(this string str, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{            
}
```

My extension method is in the main project so my unit test project can't even see it.

How can I do this? I am using Nunit.

Comment: Why can't you just reference your main project from your Nunit project?

Comment: You can't unit test something that is in a project that is not referenced by the test project. Is there a reason not to reference it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes rather an oversight! I had forgotten to add a reference so there's nothing special about testing extension methods as all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call extension methods like normal static methods by passing an instance of the type being extended as first parameter (e.g. `StringExtensions.Replace(str, dict)`).

If this extension method is located in your "main project", it should be tested in your main project's test suite, not in that of a project referencing your main project.

Answer (score 0):

Besides needing to reference your main assembly from your test assembly (which, from one of your comments, would appear to have been the problem in your particular case), there are two further possible gotchas which someone coming across this question should also be aware of:

1. The class containing the extension method has to be a non-generic, non-nested, static class. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)
2. For the test assembly to be able to access the method, either the class and method have to be public or, if they're internal, you have to "friend" your test assembly to the main one. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk.aspx)